# Why shouldn't HSQLDB be used in production for Liferay?

Tags: liferay, hsqldb

I have installed liferay as a small intranet portal that will be used by 200 persons.
The idea is to allow everybody to store data and participate on a forum.

On the Liferay Installation Guide, I have read that the HSQLDB should not be used in production.

I wondered if it applied to my case (small traffic) and what were the problems that I faced if I used it anyway.

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know: still running on HSQLDB up to now and no problem arised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because HSQLDB is very flexible, it can be used in configurations that are very fast, but not so good for data persistence. Some vendors have configured HSQLDB in this way, for demo purposes.

In general, if you use HSQLDB either version 1.8.1.3, or 2.1.x (depending on which major version is used by Liferay), and run it as a Server (instead of in-process) it should work fine for your purpose.

Change to configuration can be made very simply by modifying the HSQLDB connection URL in the application.

You can add a database backup procedure for maximum reliability.

Depending on the volume of data stored, you may want to switch to disk-based tables which consume less memory than memory-based tables.  This can be done on an existing database server.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an authoritative answer, as I don't know the reasons for Liferay's decision. But I can tell you that HSQLDB had rather severe data corruption issues in the past (before version 2.0), which are fatal for productive systems. Those issues should now be addressed according to the creators of HSQLDB. Maybe the documentation of Liferay is not up to date yet?

Comment: To be fair: those corruption were mostly caused by users not reading the manual properly. If the engine was shut down properly, there were hardly any problems.

Comment: That might be true, but I don't remember the last time I had to worry about correctly shutting down Oracle databases, in order to prevent data corruption. I'm just speculating, but that might be a good reason for Liferay to recommend not to use HSQLDB, because they're not interested in such support cases...

Comment: In the latest versions, abnormal process termination or crash will only result in the last half second (or zero if you turn off write delay) amount of data loss. This wasn't always the case some years ago.